# La referencia WCF aparece como carpeta, justo después de haber obtenido la ultima versión del servidor de control de codigo fuente

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webservice, wcf

Obtengo la última versión del código fuente de mi servicio de control de código fuente, pero las referencias del servicio WCF agregadas a un proyecto lo muestran como una carpeta, no como una referencia de servicio, no puedo actualizar la referencia u otra acción correctamente de la referencia de servicio.

Ya he tratado de descargar y volver a cargar el proyecto, sin éxito.

Por qué creen que pueda pasar esto?

Comment: Se actualizó  su control de codigo fuente o su visual studio?

Comment: No, ninguna de las 2 si te refieres a alguna actualización liberada por estas herramientas

Comment: En [esta misma pregunta en StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23993344/why-service-references-being-showed-as-folder), la respuesta aceptada dice que la causa de la problema es porque 
_"el Project tiene version de .NET Framework mas alta que lo que Visual Studio puede soportar"_. Ademas, el preguntador dice que para resolver la problema, se remueve las referencias y luego añadirlas de nuevo.